# Euler Characteristic

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, curvature

Can someone provide the exact formula for the Euler Characteristic in 4D? I know it goes as $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda}R_{\mu\nu}^{\alpha\beta}R_{\rho\lambda}^{\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$, but I am not sure about the exact numerical factor that tags along. Can you please also cite your source, I have been unable to find one.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking abou the [Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem). The Euler characteristic in 4D is
$$
\xi(M)=\frac{1}{32\pi^2}\int_M (|\text{Riem}|^2-4|\text{Ric}|^2+R^2)\,d\mu
$$
where Riem is the full Riemann curvature tensor, Ric is the Ricci tensor and $R$ is the scalar curvature.

Comment: I don't see a citation on the wikipedia page for the above expression. Also why the last two terms?

Comment: It looks like that formula is from Chern (1943). Please see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06602). Where did you get your expression from ?